# How to count rows matching multiple filters in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have data in which I'm aiming to find rows that have unique values of their `main_ID` column and then count the total of those IDs that also have either of 2 values for another ID column.

I am trying this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(main_id)) 
FROM (SELECT other_id, main_id FROM database.table WHERE other_id ='5') a INNER JOIN
(SELECT other_id, main_id FROM database.table WHERE other_id ='6') b USING (main_id)
```

This returns an error at `(SELECT` saying subquery in FROM must have an alias. I've never coded in SQL before so I'm not sure what to start with addressing this. As I understand it, it wants aliases for the 2 columns - how do I assign these for my inner join?

Comment: Maybe you have to specify in the first SELECT because main_id is in both tables (a and b). So maybe SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(a.main_id)) ... should work?

Comment: tag your database

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this structure for an inner join

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

in your query you need to add the relation between the 2 tables, in this case you need to use the primary key of both tables to make the relation between the tables.

like this example you need to add "On" stament and "table a primary key" equals "table b primary key"

```
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(main_id)) 
    FROM (SELECT other_id, main_id FROM database.table WHERE other_id ='5') a INNER JOIN
    (SELECT other_id, main_id FROM database.table WHERE other_id ='6') b on 
    a.primary_key=b.primary_key
```

You can red more [information](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) about inner join.

Answer (score 0):

your query can be optimized to this :

```
select count(*) from (
  select main_id
  from database.table
  where other_id in ('5','6')
  group by main_id
  having count(distinct other_id) = 2
) t
```